# Turn on LEDS one after another

Tags: led

I am trying to turn on LEDs one after the other so that I can start at one end and slowly turn the LEDs until it reaches the middle of the strip. The code works coming from the end of the LED strip, but not when coming from the start of the strip. From the start of the strip, it just turns on all the LEDs up until the midpoint.

```cpp
int midpoint = 30;
int R = 255;
int G = 0;
int B = 0;
for(int j = 0; j<midpoint; j++){
     //starting from the end, filling towards the middle
        for(int k = NUM_LEDS-j; k < NUM_LEDS; k++){
           leds[k] = CRGB (R, G, B);
        }
//there's some other code here in the interim
FastLED.show();
delay(20);
     //starting from the beginning, filling towards the middle
     //this is the section of code that doesn't work correctly
        for(int l = j - 1; l < midpoint; l++){
           leds[l] = CRGB (R, G, B);
           }
//more interim code
FastLED.show();
delay(20);
}
```

Comment: which number does the `for` loop start with now? .... change it so that it coun ts in the opposite direction

Comment: Ooo I just thought about how `l` is increasing through the loop instead of decreasing. I solved it by changing it to `for(int l = j; l < midpoint & l > -1; l--)`

Comment: If you have solved it, you can post an answer to your own question. If you don't, the question will stay here, unanswered.

Comment: You should fix your indentation. It's very hard to tell what code is inside the outer `j` loop since some of that code isn't indented.

Comment: You need to add more explanation. What framework you're using, and how the `leds` array relates to your `FastLED.show()` function. Does it show the LEDs that are in your `leds` array? What turns the LEDs off again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so i figured it out. The problem is that the `for` loop is starting at 0 and counting all the way up to the midpoint. What I wanted is for it to light all the LEDs that are at `j` and below. So I changed it to iterate down instead of up. Here's the new loop:

```
for(int l = j; l < midpoint & l > -1; l--){
   leds[l] = CRGB (R, G, B);
}
```

The extra qualifier `l > -1` is to make sure that it doesn't try to go below `leds[0]`

Comment: `l >= 0` is more natural than `l > -1`, the compiler will probably optimise it to the same thing.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to post the solution to your problem. Most new members don't do that.